# How do I iterate through positional variables in bash?

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

The user will give any amount of positional parameters that they want (which are all C programs). I want to make it so that all of the C programs compile. However this is not working; does anyone have a solution?

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' >> compile  
echo if [ "-o"='$1' ] >> compile  
echo then >> compile  
echo for (i=3; i<='$#'; i++) >> compile  
echo do >> compile  
echo gcc -o '$2' '${i}' >> compile  
echo fi >> compile
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "not working" part? *How* is it not working? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I do not fully comprehend what you are trying to achieve, but I am positive that a `Makefile` will probably do a better job.

Comment: it keeps giving me a syntax error here echo for (i=3; i<='$#'; i++) >> compile, normally should what i am doing work?

Comment: You need to quote all the special characters like `<` when you're echoing. Also, you need spaces around `=` in the `if` statement.

Comment: I am trying to make a bash script within in another script that will compile any c programs that it is given

Comment: do i need to use singel or double quotes?

Comment: Do you reallu want to have different `gcc -o outputfile argx` commands all writing to the same outputfile? Or do you want `gcc -o outputfile arg3 arg4 arg5 .. argn`?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a bunch of `echo` statements, use a here-doc. Putting quotes around the token after `<<` prevents expanding variables inside the here-doc.

```
cat <<'EOF' >>compile
'#!/bin/bash'
if [ "-o" = "$1" ]
then  
    for ((i=3; i <= $#; i++))
    do  
        gcc -o "$2" "${!i}"
    done
fi
EOF
```

Otherwise, you need to escape or quote all the special characters -- you were getting an error because you didn't escape the `<` in the `for()` line.

Other mistakes: you need spaces around `=` in the `[` command, and you were missing `done` at the end of the `for` loop. And to access a variable indirectly, you need to use `${!var}` syntax.

The usual way to iterate over all the arguments is with a simple:

```
for arg
```

loop. When there's no `in` after `for variable`, it loops over the arguments. You just need to remove the `-o outputfile` argument first:

```
output=$2
shift 2 # remove first 2 arguments
for arg
do
    gcc -o "$output" "$arg"
done
```

Comment: I wanted to make it so that the commands will append to another script(since i am trying to write it in another script), is there anyway i can do i t like that?

Comment: Don't you see `>>compile` on the first line of the script?

Comment: ./compile: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./compile: line 4: `for (i=3;  i  <= $#;  i++)'
i still get this error

Comment: @zee This type of `for` loop needs `((...))`

Comment: I've added another way to loop over all arguments.

Comment: @zee No, that doesn't work because variables aren't expanded inside `{start..end}`

Comment: You can write `for i in $(seq 3 $#)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would edit what you originally posted:

```
$ cat test.sh
echo -e "#!/bin/bash" > compile.sh
echo -e "if [ \"\${1}\" == \"-o\" ]; then" >> compile.sh
echo -e "\tlist_of_arguments=\${@:3} #puts all arguments starting with \$3 into one argument" >> compile.sh
echo -e "\tfor i in \${list_of_arguments}; do" >> compile.sh
echo -e "\t\techo \"gcc \${1} '\${2}' '\${i}'\"" >> compile.sh
echo -e "\tdone" >> compile.sh
echo -e "fi" >> compile.sh
$ ./test.sh
$ cat compile.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${1}" == "-o" ]; then
        list_of_arguments=${@:3} #puts all arguments starting with $3 into one argument
        for i in ${list_of_arguments}; do
                echo "gcc ${1} '${2}' '${i}'"
        done
fi
$ chmod +x compile.sh
$ ./compile.sh -o one two three four five
gcc -o 'one' 'two'
gcc -o 'one' 'three'
gcc -o 'one' 'four'
gcc -o 'one' 'five'
```

for demonstration purposed, I echoed the `gcc` command in `test.sh`. To actually run gcc instead of echoing it, change line five in `test.sh` from:

```
echo -e "\t\techo \"gcc \${1} '\${2}' '\${i}'\"" >> compile.sh
```

to

```
echo -e "\t\tgcc \${1} '\${2}' '\${i}'" >> compile.sh
```

or pipe the echo to sh like so:

```
echo -e "\t\techo \"gcc \${1} '\${2}' '\${i}'\" \| sh" >> compile.sh
```